# aChartEngine: Is it possible to display only one quadrant, with panning and zooming enabling only within it?

Tags: android, achartengine

Basically I want to restrict panning to only the first quadrant of a graph. The user should not be able to pan to negative x or y axes. But they should be able to zoom and pan inside the first quadrant only. I tried:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0); // to start off from 0 in X
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0); // to start off from 0 in Y
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false); // dont let them pan in any axis,
// but I want them to pan within the first quadrant - !problem!
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true); // let them zoom anywhere in xy quadrant
```

So the problem is once they zoom in, they cannot pan within the positive quadrant in that zoom level. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `setPanLimits` and `setZoomLimits` in the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` Javadocs.